# Set maximum requests per IP in IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, http-status-code-403

I have a web site deployed to IIS 7. One page it is has 15+ .js files linked to it.

Last two files referenced in `<head>` tag (loaded last) get 403 forbidden response from server.

I have enabled FailedRequestTracing and have been able to see a detailed error code which is 403.502.

I suppose over a very short period of time I am just pulling to much and the IIS blocks me.

Is there a way I can configure the limit to enable larger number of requests and get rid of 403.502 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. It turns out I had IIS Dynamic IP Restrictions plugin installed on the web server, with default configuration set to 20 max requests per 200 milliseconds. After increasing the limit the problem was gone.

Comment: Source: http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions